# File System security (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, security

Basically i want to discuss about file-system security,and yes i tried to search for a solution but no satisfied result.

Let me explain in details.

I have GoDaddy hosting. There are two sites installed. One on root and one is in a sub-folder. Lets say site1 and site2. Both are built with wordpress. I need to do some changes in **site2** and i do work in team so i created a FTP account for site2 and shared with team and asked them to use it so they can't do have any change in site1. but one of developer have download wp-config file of site1 and delete the database. i was wondering how can my database automatically delete(as i wasn't aware of that). After days of research i find out how he deleted the database.

> He created a php file on site2's root and copy the site1's wp-config
>   file into site2 using **dirname(getcwd())** and then using that file
>   ,he deleted the database cause wp-config file always have database
>   details.

Now i am wondering how can i give access of my site2 to the developers securely so they can't access site1.

Directory structure.

- wp-config.php
- wp-content
- wp-admin
- **site2**

  - wp-config.php
  - wp-content
  - wp-admin
  - so on ....
- another file and so on....

Comment: Create different FTP users and set different user roles for directories.

Comment: How can i that? i mean how can i set rules and what will be the rules. as i didn't created FTP for root path. I created FTP for only sub-folder.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GoDaddy hosting and how they let to create rules, but on Linux machine there is pretty simple explained how to do that: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/ but in hosting you won't have command line so you should contact GoDaddy support or read docs if they allow multiple user roles

Comment: I also know that for linux. but not goDaddy